# Construct a basis from two vectorial spaces of finite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Let $F$ a field, $V$ and $W$ $F$-vector spaces with dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively, $T: V \rightarrow W$ a linear transformation nonzero,then exist a basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$ of $V$ and $W$ such that

$$[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   I_s & 0_{s \times (n-s)} \\
   0_{(m-s) \times s} & 0_{(m-s) \times (n-s)} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

is the matrix associated to $T$ with respect the basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$ with $I_s \in M_s(F)$ the unit matrix where s is the dimension of the image of $T$.

This exercise its really difficult for me, i tried to take a basis of $V$ and extend it to $W$ but i stuck here some help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin with a basis $\{e_{s+1},\dots,e_n\}$ for $kerT$. Extend it to a basis $\beta=\{e_1,\dots,e_s,e_{s+1},\dots,e_n\}$ of $V$. Now consider $f_i=T(e_i)\ \mbox{for}\  i=1,\dots,s$ and we have $\{f_1,\dots,f_s\}$ a basis of the image of $T$. Finally you complete it to a basis $\gamma=\{f_1.\dots.f_s,f_{s+1},\dots,f_m\}$ of $W$. You can check that the matrix of $T$ in these basis is the desired one.

Comment: i tried to do your answer but i stuck with the calculus and extend of the basis, can you help me more please

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you understand the construction of the basis? Or the problem is to verify that the matrix is actually the one you want?

Comment: yea the problem is verify that the matrix is the desired matrix, i can't get the matrix zeros with respectively size, i.e, $0_{sx(n-s)}$ and the other zeros.